# Delete all lines which don't match a pattern

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, gawk

I am looking for a way to delete all lines that do not follow a specific pattern (from a txt file).

Pattern which I need to keep the lines for:

`x//x/x/x/5/x/`

`x` could be any amount of characters, numbers or special characters.

`5` is always a combination of alphanumeric - 5 characters - e.g Xf1Lh, always appears after the 5th forward slash.

`/` are actual forward slashes.

Input:

`abc//a/123/gds:/4AdFg/f3dsg34/
 y35sdf//x/gd:df/j5je:/x/x/x
 yh//x/x/x/5Fsaf/x/
 45wuhrt//x/x/dsfhsdfs54uhb/
 5ehys//srt/fd/ab/cde/fg/x/x`

Desired output:

`abc//a/123/gds:/4AdFg/f3dsg34/
 yh//x/x/x/5Fsaf/x/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` selects lines according to a regular expression and your `x//x/x/x/5/x/` just needs minor changes to make it into a regular expression:

```
$ grep -E '.*//.*/.*/.*/[[:alnum:]]{5}/.*/' file
abc//a/123/gds:/4AdFg/f3dsg34/
yh//x/x/x/5Fsaf/x/
```

Explanation:

- *"x could be any amount of characters, numbers or special characters"*.  In a regular expression that is `.*` where `.` means any character and `*` means zero or more of the preceding character (which in this case is `.`).
- *"5 is always a combination of alphanumeric - 5 characters"*.  In POSIX regular expressions, `[[:alnum:]]` means any alphanumeric character.  `{5}` means five of the preceding.  `[[:alnum:]]` is unicode-safe.

#### Possible improvements

One issue is how `x` should be interpreted.  In the above, `x` was allowed to be *any character*.  As triplee points out, however, another reasonable interpretation is that `x` should be any character *except* `/`.  In that case:

```
grep -E '[^/]*//[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/[[:alnum:]]{5}/[^/]*/' file
```

Also, we might want this regex to match only *complete* lines.  In that case, we can either surround the regex with `^` an `$` or we can use grep's `-x` option:

```
grep -xE '[^/]*//[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/[[:alnum:]]{5}/[^/]*/' file
```

Comment: Does GnuWin32 grep provide the same functionality as the actual grep? With your explanation, the regex makes perfect sense to me, however putting the example input in `test.txt` and running it like so `grep -E '.*//.*/.*/.*/[[:alnum:]]{5}/.*/' c:\test.txt > c:\out.txt` the output file comes back empty.

Comment: @user327685 Hmm. I am using "GNU grep v2.25" on Linux.  What shell are you running under?  On Windows, some shells requires different quoting.  IIRC, running under some Windows shells may require replacing single quotes, `'`, with double-quotes, `"`.

Comment: I got it to work once replacing `'` with `"` (I am on Windows) with the test input, I then tried on actual data (800MB file) which came back empty, I then retried it on the test input again, and now it keeps failing, empty result. I have now installed cygwin and trying there but keeps failing as well, this is getting really frustrating, any ideas?

Comment: turns out the text files were binary encoded for some reason, it worked now. Thanks!

Comment: For added precision, replace `.*` with `[^/]*` throughout. `.` coud match a slash, throwing off the field numbering. You shoud also add `^` and `$` line anchors to prevent the regex from matching mid-line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-P` option for extended perl support like

```
grep -P "^(?:[^/]*/){5}[A-Za-z0-9]{5}/(?:/|$)" input
```

***Output***

```
abc//a/123/gds:/4AdFg/f3dsg34/
yh//x/x/x/5Fsaf/x/
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Start of line
 (?: #Non capturing group
    [^/]* #Match anything except /
    / #Match / literally
 ){5} #Repeat this 5 times
 [A-Za-z0-9]{5} #Match alphanumerics. You can use \w if you want to allow _ along with [A-Za-z0-9]
 (?: #Non capturing group
   / #Next character should be /
    | #OR
   $ #End of line
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I was figuring out how to do it in awk at the same time as the other answer and came up with:

```
awk -F/ 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}$2==""&&$6~/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]/&&NF=8'
```

The awk I worked it out on didn't support the `{5}` regexp frob.

Comment: I was under the impression that all Awk dialects would support `{5}` repetiton. Which Awk was this?

Comment: You should add `^` and `$` anchors to the regex.

Comment: I noticed that `{5}` problem also. Apparently I had `mawk` which didn't support it, `gawk` instead does.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed and in place edit to *delete all lines that do not follow a specific pattern (from a txt file)*:

```
$ sed -i.bak -n "/.*\/\/.*\/.*\/.*\/[a-zA-Z0-9]\{5\}\/.*\//p" test.in
$ cat test.in
abc//a/123/gds:/4AdFg/f3dsg34/
yh//x/x/x/5Fsaf/x/
```

`-i.bak` in place edit creating a test.in.bak backup file, `-n` quiet, do not print non-matches to output
and  `".../p"` print matches.